Find isolated word in string with Boost spirit
I'm a newbie and maybe it's even something easy to get.
But what is the best way to write a boost::spirit parser that allows you to match a word within a string only if the word is isolated?
Example:
If I would like to find the word "ma" (case insensitive) only if this is isolated.

"mare"          -> no match

"altamarea"     -> no match

"Roma"          -> no match

"no ma va bene" -> match!

"Ma anche no!"      -> match!



Where you'd write "ma" to match "ma" anywhere, write e.g.

"ma" >> &qi::space to require a space. Note this will not match at the end of input because no space follows.

"ma" >> !qi::graph to require NO non-space. This WILL match at the end of input (because no non-space follows)


Detecting distinct starts of identifiers is usually implicit in the surrounding grammar.
Simple Demo
Live On Coliru Using X3
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

void run_tests(auto p) {
    for (std::string_view input : {
             "mare",          // -> no match
             "altamarea",     // -> no match
             "Roma",          // -> no match
             "ma",            // ???
             "no ma va bene", // -> match!
             "Ma anche no!",  // -> match
         }) {
        auto f = begin(input), l = end(input);
        auto found = parse(f, l, boost::spirit::x3::seek[p]);
        std::cout                             //
            << std::setw(16) << quoted(input) //
            << " -> " << std::boolalpha << found << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    auto ma      = x3::no_case["ma"];

    std::cout << " ------- Naive:\n";
    run_tests(ma);
    std::cout << " ------- Positive lookahead:\n";
    run_tests(ma >> &x3::space);
    std::cout << " ------- Negative lookahead:\n";
    run_tests(ma >> !x3::graph);
    std::cout << " ------- Hybrid:\n";
    run_tests(ma >> &(x3::space | x3::eoi));
}

Printing
 ------- Naive:
          "mare" -> true
     "altamarea" -> true
          "Roma" -> true
            "ma" -> true
 "no ma va bene" -> true
  "Ma anche no!" -> true
 ------- Positive lookahead:
          "mare" -> false
     "altamarea" -> false
          "Roma" -> false
            "ma" -> false
 "no ma va bene" -> true
  "Ma anche no!" -> true
 ------- Negative lookahead:
          "mare" -> false
     "altamarea" -> false
          "Roma" -> true
            "ma" -> true
 "no ma va bene" -> true
  "Ma anche no!" -> true
 ------- Hybrid:
          "mare" -> false
     "altamarea" -> false
          "Roma" -> true
            "ma" -> true
 "no ma va bene" -> true
  "Ma anche no!" -> true

Demonstrating arbitrary surrounding grammar:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

void run_tests(auto p) {
    for (std::string_view input : {
             "mare",          // -> no match
             "altamarea",     // -> no match
             "Roma",          // -> no match
             "ma",            // ???
             "no ma va bene", // -> match!
             "Ma anche no!",  // -> match
         }) {
        auto f = begin(input), l = end(input);
        auto ignored = x3::lexeme[!p >> +x3::graph];
        auto found   = phrase_parse(f, l, *ignored >> p, x3::space);
        std::cout                             //
            << std::setw(16) << quoted(input) //
            << " -> " << std::boolalpha << found << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    auto ma = x3::no_case["ma"];

    std::cout << " ------- Negative lookahead:\n";
    run_tests(x3::lexeme[ma >> !x3::graph]);
    std::cout << " ------- Hybrid:\n";
    run_tests(x3::lexeme[ma >> &(x3::space | x3::eoi)]);
}

Printing
 ------- Negative lookahead:
          "mare" -> false
     "altamarea" -> false
          "Roma" -> false
            "ma" -> true
 "no ma va bene" -> true
  "Ma anche no!" -> true
 ------- Hybrid:
          "mare" -> false
     "altamarea" -> false
          "Roma" -> false
            "ma" -> true
 "no ma va bene" -> true
  "Ma anche no!" -> true


You never showed any code, so we don't know whether you use X3 or Qi. Here's the last example translated to Qi: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb1c559c23375b72
